# getting values from dictionary with clickhouse database

Tags: dictionary, select, networking, clickhouse

I am learning Clickhouse databse and I have a challenge with some lab:

I have a dictionary with the following structure / schema:

> CREATE DICTIONARY reputation_rbl_db (　    network String,　    source String,　    category String　,asn UInt32,country String　)　PRIMARY KEY network　SOURCE(FILE(　    path '/var/lib/clickhouse/user_files/rbl_database.csv'　    format 'CSVWithNames'　))　LAYOUT(IP_TRIE())　LIFETIME(300);

I have a lot of rows like:

```
┌─network────────┬─source────┬─category────┬───asn─┬─country─┐
│ 1.1.109.250/32 │ blacklist │ rbl │  2519 │ JP      │
│ 1.10.16.0/20   │ blacklist │ rb  │    22 │ CN      │
│ 1.12.45.0/24   │ blacklist │ rbl │ 45090 │ CN      │
└────────────────┴───────────┴─────────────┴───────┴─────────┘
```

I need to find the SELECT which search if the IP 1.10.15.55 is under some network with CIDR at the dictionary, something to

SELECT * from reputation_rbl_db where network= '1.10.15.55/32'

and the response needs to be something like:

> 1.10.16.0/20, blacklist, rbl, 22, CN

is there any way to find this select ?

Thanks in advance

Max

i tried with:

SELECT * FROM dictionary('reputation_rbl_db') where network = '1.10.15.55/32' but do not work because the select not find the network which has this IP

Answer (score 0):

IP Address `1.10.15.55` is NOT in CIDR range `1.10.16.0/20` ;).

Anyway,

There is a `IPv4CIDRToRange` function in Clickhouse:

```
SELECT IPv4CIDRToRange(toIPv4('1.10.16.0'), 20)

Query id: 598aa84f-6297-4d99-8b0c-29a571370024

┌─IPv4CIDRToRange(toIPv4('1.10.16.0'), 20)─┐
│ ('1.10.16.0','1.10.31.255')              │
└──────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

You can also use Clickhouse bit functions (or bit operators in other DBMSs):

```
SELECT
    CAST(CAST('255.255.240.0', 'IPv4'), 'UInt32') AS mask,
    CAST(bitAnd(CAST(CAST('1.10.16.0', 'IPv4'), 'UInt32'), mask), 'IPv4') AS lower,
    CAST(bitOr(lower, bitNot(CAST(mask, 'UInt32'))), 'IPv4') AS upper

┌───────mask─┬─lower─────┬─upper───────┐
│ 4294963200 │ 1.10.16.0 │ 1.10.31.255 │
└────────────┴───────────┴─────────────┘
```

Or you can just utilize `isIPAddressInRange` function (easy way):

```
SELECT isIPAddressInRange('1.10.15.55', '1.10.16.0/20')

┌─isIPAddressInRange('1.10.15.55', '1.10.16.0/20')─┐
│                                                0 │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM reputation_rbl_db 
WHERE isIPAddressInRange(extract('1.10.15.55/32', '[^/]*'), network)
```